# File /usr/include/linux/limits.h has been modified since the precompiled header

Tags: azerothcore

Using Ubuntu 18.04. After trying to update an installation of [AzerothCore](http://azerothcore.org) that was quite behind the latest master branch, I got the following error when executing `make`:

> File '/usr/include/linux/limits.h' has been modified since the precompiled header

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by doing a clean compile. Which means, deleting the `build` directory, creating it again and start from the `cmake` command the compilation process (followed by `make` and `make install`).

Comment: When there is a new file added, you need to rerun cmake (and delete the build directory). So if you had a very far behind revision, you should've done it by default. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: it was not very far, more or less 3 weeks, but I think you're right